# HBaseImportJob : cannot find column family though it exist

Tags: hive, hbase, hdfs, sqoop

Hi Im facing an issue sqooping data from hive to hbase.

Im using the HBaseImportJob from apache sqoop.
It is unable to find the column family. Although column family exists in the table description

```
NAME => 'temp_table', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'cf', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '1', V true                                                       
 ERSIONS => '3', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_ME                                                            
 MORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]}
```

The code part where error is comming is :

```
// Check to see if the table exists.
    HTableDescriptor tableDesc = null;
    byte [] familyBytes = Bytes.toBytes(familyName);
    HColumnDescriptor colDesc = new HColumnDescriptor(familyBytes);
    if (!admin.tableExists(tableName)) {
        if (options.getCreateHBaseTable()) {
            // Create the table.
            LOG.info("Creating missing HBase table " + tableName);
            tableDesc =  new HTableDescriptor(tableName);
            tableDesc.addFamily(colDesc);
            admin.createTable(tableDesc);
        } else {
            LOG.warn("Could not find HBase table " + tableName);
            LOG.warn("This job may fail. Either explicitly create the table,");
            LOG.warn("or re-run with --hbase-create-table.");
        }
    } else {
        // Table exists, so retrieve their current version
        tableDesc = admin.getTableDescriptor(Bytes.toBytes(tableName));
        // Check if current version do have specified column family
        if (!tableDesc.hasFamily(familyBytes)) {
            if (options.getCreateHBaseTable()) {
                // Create the column family.
                LOG.info("Creating missing column family " + familyName);
                admin.disableTable(tableName);
                admin.addColumn(tableName, colDesc);
                admin.enableTable(tableName);
            } else {
                LOG.warn("Could not find column family " + familyName + " in table "
                    + tableName);
                LOG.warn("This job may fail. Either create the column family,");
                LOG.warn("or re-run with --hbase-create-table.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error :

```
2015-04-05 23:38:58,643 WARN org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob: Could not find column family cf in table temp_table
2015-04-05 23:38:58,643 WARN org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob: This job may fail. Either create the column family,
2015-04-05 23:38:58,643 WARN org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.HBaseImportJob: or re-run with --hbase-create-table
```

Any Idea ?

Comment: what does the function `getCreateHBaseTable()` do ?

Comment: Using the standard HBaseImport job provided by Apache. I think as name suggest would create the table in HBase if specified true in parameter.